# TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable and appear two columns instead of 1

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

What I am trying to achieve with my program is, reading a csv file by using `pd.read_csv` and then try to print single column and then build a dictionary based on the selected column. I am using `gensim` library to make dictionary.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('items.csv', sep='\t')
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
corpus = df['id']

item_id = df.id
print item_id
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(corpus)
```

By above code I got following output:

[Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiOYI.png)

**and this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-4365f51dd2a7> in <module>()
      7 item_id = df.id
      8 print item_id
----> 9 dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(corpus)
     10 
     11 # review dictionary size

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/corpora/dictionary.pyc in __init__(self, documents, prune_at)
     56 
     57         if documents is not None:
---> 58             self.add_documents(documents, prune_at=prune_at)
     59 
     60     def __getitem__(self, tokenid):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/corpora/dictionary.pyc in add_documents(self, documents, prune_at)
    117 
    118             # update Dictionary with the document
--> 119             self.doc2bow(document, allow_update=True)  # ignore the result, here we only care about updating token ids
    120 
    121         logger.info(

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/corpora/dictionary.pyc in doc2bow(self, document, allow_update, return_missing)
    143         # Construct (word, frequency) mapping.
    144         counter = defaultdict(int)
--> 145         for w in document:
    146             counter[w if isinstance(w, unicode) else unicode(w, 'utf-8')] += 1
    147 

TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

**Other question** is that why I get 2 columns everytime instead of single column?
I am completely new to python. Please consider this while answering.

Thanks

"id title   career_level    discipline_id   industry_id country region  latitude    longitude   employment  tags    created_at  active_during_test"
"19 4298526"    4316979 "2643380    3   18  15  ch  0   47.4    8.5 1   1471052"    2072458 2512557 1077976 2643380 137600  1780765 1156891 2809945 4298526 2849590 4316979 2338707 954599  "366679 1438466400  0"
"116    822375  2   20  22  de  1   48.4    10.0    2   469901" 3938421 "3792911    1438812000  0"
"140    232343" "3582227    3   12  15  at  0   47.3    11.1    2   3787103"    "2360643    1444255200  0"
"161    2804344"    1768488 "1662103    3   15  21  de  0   48.1    16.9    1   281693" 2788092 1185123 1768488 675557  1136325 1662103 4499767 3712454 3487119 3026440 751355  798840  3015937 4375914 "624061 1436911200  1"
"190    3907924 3   14  15  de  6   53.6    10.0    1   4317479"    4151211 38045   "4425481    1438812000  0"
"244    3772791"    "1938824    3   15  11  de  10  51.2    7.1 1   3792911"    1167575 "1937646    1445814000  1"
"268    3582227 2   19  21  at  0   48.2    16.4    1   3792911"    2971982 3668574 "2359966    1437688800  1"
"328    3836325"    "2912912    3   12  15  de  10  50.9    6.9 1   2632767"    2711443 4344735 2575161 751977  573207  1084525 799173  2076438 4252882 2245760 2603154 4151211 4498297 23183   "732298 1438552800  0"
"344        3   9   15  de  9   51.2    6.8 1   4432807"    4152078 4421717 "2850218    1439330400  0"
"350    2202904"    "76751  3   20  14  de  5   53.1    8.8 1   155778" 695299  3876540 1454092 4151211 798840  4329775 265439  3010695 177543  "3129740    1436738400  0"
"380    3478136 3   15  8   de  9   52.2    8.5 1   1364799"    2194612 3080025 4499767 234916  "4151211    1434837600  0"
"383    3586425"    2608520 1919452 604369  "3347280    4   19  2   de  2   50.1    11.3    1   289576" 4173578 4324548 3586425 2969837 3726822 2231031 "4499767    1437084000  0"
"403    2573697"    "1072229    3   13  11  de  7   50.1    8.2 1   2856334"    4160943 649642  4011133 1272071 1072229 1643500 "174682 1437084000  0"
"488    3267961"    4305724 "4432807    1   18  14  de  9   52.0    8.5 1   3872880"    191860  675557  624061  1465860 3026440 4064526 3129740 1819239 234916  "2683873    1437688800  0"
"510    18903   3   15  15  ch  0   47.3    8.6 1   1339458"    3792911 4501345 2085991 46678   910951  4263126 3972474 1604815 53586   1443376 3240672 2735573 "3458589    1440453600  0"
"572    4063158 5   19  8   de  3   52.5    13.4    1   4432807"    3596952 3626570 3937157 4384650 3347266 "3938421    1432677600  0"
"573    1766375"    "1506826    1   18  15  de  3   52.5    13.4    1   3287066"    4323739 3600555 3466544 3487119 1443376 1272071 3087774 3472807 4228890 "3726822    1437688800  0"
"653        3   15  11  de  7   50.6    8.7 1   4432807"    3487119 3843067 4011133 692505  213841  1571903 "4321558    1437084000  0"
"693    4344735"    4318371 2966139 1567907 "2608520    3   16  11  non_dach    0   41.8    -87.7   1   3176219"    4328463 2026458 2846960 751977  24363   2632767 3407033 3498937 2224459 910951  33048   4344735 2735573 2076438 889442  798840  1279904 3726822 2231031 1105913 1295675 "251535 NULL    0"

Comment: can you paste an extract from your csv?

Comment: Isn't the left column just the row number?  Review `pandas` display standards.

Comment: @FrancescoNazzaro, thanks for the reply. I have pasted some rows in the question above

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks for the reply. left column is row numbers only.